# i want to show only some FAQ categories on CMS page magento

Tags: javascript, php, xml, html, magento

Im currently trying to put FAQ's categories on CMS Page on Magento.

Actually im using Padoo FAQ Module im im trying to put it working with the next code, used in CMS Page Layout (XML)

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="faq/faq" name="faq" template="padoofaq/faq.phtml">
            <block type="faq/faq" name="faq.group" >
                <action method="setTemplate"> 
                    <template>padoofaq/faq_group.phtml</template> 
                                <action method="setGroupId">
                                         <category_id>3</category_id>
                                </action>
                </action>
            </block>
         </block>
</reference>
```

Im currently working on next code trying to call only one category, but without sucess...

```
<action method="setGroupId">
  <category_id>3</category_id>
</action>
```

Hope some can help me,
Thanks a lot!